# How to see column labels in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have code like below:

```
table_1 = new JTable();

table_1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
    new Object[][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
    },
    new String[] {
        "Product Code", "Description", "Price", "Quantity", "Total ", "Discount", "Remarks"
    }
));
```

I want to see column header names. I tried with this code, but I cant see the names. I want to know how to do that?

Also, I also want to set the cell value which is coming from a `JTextField`.

Comment: don't understand the question, you already _do_ have column names?

Comment: question is not clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column names won't show up until you add `table_1` to a `JScrollPane`, like they show in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: You can use `table_1.getModel().setValueAt()` to update you table.